# User defined stack vs system stack

Tags: loops, memory-management, recursion, stack, heap-memory

While using a for loop if we use a user-defined stack then does that stack get created in system heap memory? And user-defined stack will take much more time to get filled as compared to system stack? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heap is all the memory that is not system stack so yes. A user defined stack would reside on the heap.

It all depends. Usually the system stack is quite fast but I imagine you want to use a user defined one to not blow the stack which implies we are dealing with a runtime that adds it's frame which has payload even when nothing is pushed (no arguments). In that case a stack based on an array might be faster since you are pushing less data on it at each iteration.

A stack based on other data structures will vary on efficiency but ultimately never get as efficient as an array.

I would have used the system stack until I know for sure I needed something else (In most languages you can set the stack size) and you end up writing less code which is readable and understandable.

If you need to do a stack then do it for readability first. Thus most likely it becomes slower than just increasing memory for system stack.

I bet you probably know the [3 rules of optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization)